# Array keeps being over written

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a method which adds a string to an Mutable array. However everytime I call that method it overwrites the last entered element.

Below is my code:
brain.h

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *equation;
```

brain.m

```
@synthesize equation = _equation;
-(double)performCalculation:(NSString *)operation
{

double left ;
double right;

left = [self setOperand];
right = [self setOperand];

result = left + right;

NSString *leftString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f + %f = %f", left, right,result];

_equation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];
[self.equation addObject: leftString];


//Checking entries
        for(NSString * myStr in _equation) {
            NSLog(myStr);
       }
```

}

Comment: `_equation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];` re-initializes the array. That's why results are being overwritten.

Comment: Where should i move that line so that it doesnt overwrite?

Comment: Into your initializer, `- (instancetype)init:` or the like.

Comment: -(double _equation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25])performCalculation:(NSString *)operation like that?

Comment: equation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25] to the place where code will be called only one(as @mattt descibed ), to initialize the 'equation', and then call performCalculation whenerever you need that.

Comment: Note that with modern Objective-C you don't need the @synthesize line: the compiler will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
_equation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];
```

line from your function. And set it in your initializer. Also it will be good to not use hard coded numbers(25).

Comment: Im a bit confused. Which constructor do I place it in? Im fairly new to Objective-C and am still trying to learn the basics haha

Comment: How do you create brain object? Add following in your .m file:

- (id) init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self != nil) {
equation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25]
  }
  return self;
}